# Blocked by play protect [ Released apk]

Tags: android, google-play

i have published my app in Google Play ,and now i want to send an update to fix some bugs,when i generate singed APK and test it in my phone before publish it in Google play a Blocked by play protect dialog appears with this message (play protect doesn't recognize this app's developer,apps from unknown developers can something be unsafe) ,my app doens't have any dangerous permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER_HINTS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

i don't know what i do,I'm afraid if i publish my app with this issue maybe Google Play will take action of it

Comment: update your app on play store then you will able to see wither it is for permission issue or something need to be change in store listing

Comment: @Satyavrat i'm afraid if i publish it i will get suspend or something like this

Comment: their must me some error type of thing in play store if its in store listing otherwise error is clearly mention their for what your app is not publish..

Comment: and also if your app is blocked you can easily re publish app by following guideline provided by google.

Comment: @Satyavrat the previous version of my app is already published in google play without any problem,i have a trouble just with the new version wish is not published yet in google play, when i try to test it before i publish it get this message (play protect ..)

Comment: Try to generate a signed apk and install in your phone, or ask to some friends try it. It seems to be some play protect issue with debug applications.

Comment: i test it in 3 devices and i get the same alert,I'm afraid if i publish my app with this issue maybe Google Play will take action of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If anyone runs into the same problem just publish your app, and don't worry about this warning

Answer (score 1):

I faced a similar issue. But I created an internal test track in the Play console, added my own Google account to the test track. I published it on the internal track and installed the google play version. Google Play app showed that there was an update and went through the update process.

That is the best way to test it.

Comment: and what happened after that ?

Comment: @pic Play protect was falsely detecting my app as malicious. You might also be getting the issue if you have signed your package with google play signing key. So if you signed with a release key from your android studio, and installed it on your device, there might be a conflict with Google play signed key package...

Answer (score 1):

If your app has no malware then it won't be an issue. It is probably because you use Google Play App Signing, so installs from Google Play use a different signing key than the version you are just installing using adb.

If you install using a Google Play internal test track then you can check it works with the real Google Play key.

Answer (score -2):

On your device Go to **Google play store -> Settings -> Disable Protect my updates** and try installing your singed APK

Comment: i know this, but can you please confirm that if i publish it in google play i will not have any issue ?I'm afraid if i publish my app with this issue maybe Google Play will take action of it

Comment: As far as I am concern I haven't faced any issue after publishing my app on play store after facing a similar situation. You can publish your app on alpha if you wish to test the same.